# Rank of difference of matrix square roots

Tags: matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

Let $A, B$ be $N \times N$ symmetric positive definite matrices and $A^{1/2}, B^{1/2}$ their symmetric, positive definite square roots. Furthermore, suppose that
$$ C = A-B$$
has rank at most $R \in \mathbb N$, with $ R \ll N$.

Is it true, that the rank of

$$ D = A^{1/2} - B^{1/2}$$
may be bounded by a constant multiple of $R$?

Comment: Are we given that $C$ is itself positive semidefinite?

Comment: For what it's worth, this is definitely possible in the case that $A$ or $B$ is a multiple of the identity matrix.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you! $C$ is not necessarily positive definite (though I would be happy to see the argument in this case as well!)